# C# Drawing.Graphics FromImage OutofMemoryException when passed a Bitmap with Format16bppGrayScale

Tags: c#, bitmap, out-of-memory, system.drawing

I'm passing Drawing.Graphics.FromImage a Drawing.Bitmap with its pixelformat set to Format16bppGrayScale, but this is throwing a System.OutOfMemoryException (when pixelformat is left unset, the error is not thrown).

```
            Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(imgWidth, imgHeight,PixelFormat.Format16bppGrayScale);
        gr = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
```

imgWidth and imgHeight are 40 and 58 respectively - too low for it to actually be out of memory. On other threads on this site I've seen it mentioned that System.Drawing can sometimes throw out of memory exceptions when this is not the actual cause of the error, so I assume this is the case here.
Thanks

Comment: From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.graphics.fromimage?view=netframework-4.7.2#remarks): "This method also throws an exception if the image has any of the following pixel formats. Undefined, DontCare, Format16bppRgb555, **Format16bppGrayScale**" (commas and emphasis mine)

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 I understand 16bpp grayscale, since it exceeds 1 byte per colour component... but now I honestly wonder why the heck they didn't support 16bpp Rgb555...